# Dress-up game programming problems

Tags: flash

I had been made a dress-up game...I arranged the set of dress images into to be the different frames of movieclips with the next button.

When i drag the dress images from frame1 movieclip and put on to the stage(avatar),the images from frame1 movieclip will be dissapeared when i clicked on the next button going to the frame2.How do i need to do to make the dress images from frame1 remain on stage even when i clicked the next button to frame2 ?Which coding should i use to make the image stay on stage?....

Comment: Try to narrow the focus of your question a little more.  Decompose the problem into each step that needs to take place, then figure out where you're having problems understanding the technical details.  Then rephrase your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

addChild your "dresses" to a movieclip that covers all your frames range.
example:

[timeline_image http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2999/screenshot20100301at348.png](http://img27.imageshack.us/img27/2999/screenshot20100301at348.png)